# When using URL rewrite files are included multiple times?

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, coldfusion-10

I am developing a new site in ColdFusion 10 and doing some url rewriting using the .htaccess file.  I have three rules that work very well when I call them without other includes. When I wrap them in includes, I get an error.

Here are my rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^advertise$ /index.cfm?Section=Advertise
RewriteRule ^bike/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?Section=Bike&BikeID=$1&FeatureID=$2
RewriteRule ^bike/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?Section=Bike&BikeID=$1
```

The index page figures our which section to show and calls includes the appropriate file wrapped around a header and footer, like this:

```
include "header.cfm"; 
include "#VARIABLES.Section#.cfm";
include "footer.cfm";
```

The problem is, it doesn't quite work for the "Bike" pages, the second two rules.  It appears that the header file is included several times, which makes the links to the CSS and other files bad, which messes up the page.  If I comment out the header and footer includes, everything works just fine, but there's no header or footer, which is not what I want.

```
// include "header.cfm"; 
include "#VARIABLES.Section#.cfm";
// include "footer.cfm";
```

Is there something in the url rewrite  rules that causes the bike pages to be loaded several times and then fail?

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/
```

You can try the page here and see the problem by clicking the links.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE

When I make all of my links absolute by including the entire URL, the problem goes away.

```
<cfoutput>
<link href="#APP.Home#/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</cfoutput>
```

Still, I should NOT have to include an absolute path to files. Any hints as to why this isn't working for me?

UPDATE

```
// THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM
<base href="#APP.Home#/">
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

// THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM
<link href="#APP.Home#/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

// THIS IS THE PROBLEM
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Could be that you're refering to the URL variable "section" as "variables.section" rather than "URL.section"

Comment: Did you fix the issue?  I don't see anything wrong in your included site link after clicking through all the pages.

Comment: Jake, I took Section out of the URL scope and put it into the VARIABLES scope. I didn't include the code that does that. I did "fix" the problem.  Instead of hard coding the absolute path to in the links, I used <base href="http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/"> in the head. That is the very first time I have ever used that <base>. I really don't see how this was the problem though. Is that common when using URL rewrites?

Comment: It's not something that I've experienced. The only thing that I found "odd" about your rewrites was the lack of [L,QSA] which I throw into mine. You might want to have a rule for http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/bike/ as well.

Comment: "it appears that the header file is included several times"... *is* it, or is it not? IE: do you end up with multiple copies of the header mark-up (eg: multiple `<link>` tags), or are you just getting the wrong CSS?  Have you looked at the rewrite logs to see if the rules are being executed in the way you expect them to (ie: once per requested file, and only the correct files are being matched, and they *are* being matched)? Also, are you using Apache or IIS (the assumption has been made that it's Apache, but IIS can run .htaccess files too, with Helicon's ISAPI Rewrite Module).  Pls clarify.

Comment: @nosilleg: I'd be wary of advocating adding QSA as a matter of course.  My position is that that should only be used in situations where the RewriteRule doesn't consider all the query params that might be on the URL, so need to be catered for.  It should not unilaterally pump everything on the URL through to the app server.

Comment: @AdamCameron are there security/performance concerns with including QSA, or just a feeling that it's not "clean"?  (with canonical link tags being used to mitigate SEO concerns)

Comment: @nosilleg: Security concerns, really.  Why allow things through on the  URL that you're not expecting?  If a CFM is expecting a param of `foo`, which could take a user-specified value, but it doesn't expect anything else, why pass the rest of it through?  That said, there'd be arguments both ways in some circumstances, I just mean to do it *unilaterally* might not be the best approach.

Comment: @AdamCameron Since anyone can put anything into a URL, I usually take the approach of including QSA by default and only removing it if I know I don't care about any query strings. (such as 301ing an old site to a new one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen because you didn't tell Apache to stop parsing on match. Try to make rules look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^advertise$ /index.cfm?Section=Advertise [L]
RewriteRule ^bike/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?Section=Bike&BikeID=$1&FeatureID=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^bike/([0-9]+)/ /index.cfm?Section=Bike&BikeID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I was hoping that advice like yours was a solution. It's not. I have the same issue after adding [L]. Funny, I didn't see any examples using [L] in all of the tutorials I found.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever your problem is, trying to make a connection between .htaccess rewrite rules and files included by CF is the wrong troubleshooting approach.

Rewrite rules are applied only to the incoming request: the document requested in the address bar (for example) of the browser.

When one includes a file, it's not making a request, so the webserver (and accordingly the rewrite module) are not involved.

I imagine if you simply browse to the rewritten URL for the bikes page (eg: /index.cfm?Section-Bije&BikeID=12345) you'd see the same problem.  This demonstrates the rewriting is not part of the problem.

Factor this notion out of your investigation, and just look at how your files are being included.  A good simple place to start is to just turn debugging on, and look at the execution time dispay using the TREE view.  This'll give you an idea of where/how/why you're calling in your templates multiple times.

Comment: I totally agree that this is not the right solution. It does however, perfectly mask the problem. I will continue to search for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is related, but I did run into a similar issue with FW/1.  By tailing the rewrite.log I could see every `cfinclude` that did NOT actually exist was actually going through Apache.  I added `[NS]` to the .htaccess and it went away:

```
# rewrite rules, NS skips rewrite rule for internal sub-requests
# for FW/1, removes index.cfm from the URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.cfm/$1 [NS,L]
```

Comment: Reading this again, I'm not sure if it the same issue that I was having...my rule basically was getting into an infinite rewrite loop, doesn't look like the same for yours.  I would recommend enabling Rewrite logging...just start at a low trace level and increase as necessary - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: I am suspecting that I am getting into a rewrite loop of some kind. I am on a hosted server and have no access to logs and such. I will give your suggestion a try later today. Thanks!

Comment: As per my previous response, I recommend stop looking at the rewrites.  They are *almost certainly* not going to be causing what you're seeing.  Troubleshoot your problem by browsing the the rewritten URL pattern, ie: don't browse to `/bike/123/456/`, browse to `/index.cfm?Section=Bike&BikeID=123&FeatureID=456`.  I'm reasonably confident you'll see the same problem on that expanded URL as you do on the rewritten one.

Comment: +1 to Adam's point.  If the issue goes away when browsing the rewritten URL, then it has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.  Also, I can't imagine trying to figure out rewrite problems if you cannot enable logging.